# Prepending text to jQuery (this).text

Tags: jquery

I have this line which outputs the name value of a span tag:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr("name"));
```

What's the best way to add a character before the 'name' value, specifically a dollar sign ($).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).text("$" + $(this).attr("name"));
```

Using the `+` operator with two Strings will concatenate them.

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("$") >= 0) {
      $(this).html($(this).attr("name"));
    } else {
      $(this).html("$" + $(this).attr("name"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="2000">2000</button>
```

The example above toggles the appearance of `$` in the button inner HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
$(this).text(`$${$('.myDiv').attr("name")}`);
```

Here is an example:

```js
$('.span').text(`$${$('.myDiv').attr("name")}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv" name="hello"></div><br>
<span class="span"></span>
```